# What is wrong with this C++ code

Tags: c++, calculator

I'm new to programming and I've decided to try and make a Calculator that can do stuff other than simple Arithmetic. I have not finished yet, I was just testing to see if it was working so far. As I ran it, and went through Arithmetic by pressing 1 it just stops. Can someone please tell me what Ive done wrong? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int frsnum
    int secnum
    int arithchoice;
    int answer;
    int x;
    cout << "Welcome to the advanced calculator!" << endl;
    cout << "What are you trying to calculate: Simple Arithmetic < 1 >" << endl;
    cout << "                                  Systems of Equations < 2 >" << endl;
    cout << "                                  Matrices < 3 >" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    if(x == 1)
        {
            cout << "Add <1>|Subtract <2>|Multiply <3>|Divide <4>";
            cin << arithchoice;
        }

    if(arithchoice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Whats the first number: "
            cin >> frsnum;
            cout << "And the second number: "
            cin >> secnum;
            answer = frsnum + secnum;
            cout << "That would be: " answer << endl
        }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably `cin << arithchoice`.

Comment: The first thing I noticed are the missing semicolons around the declarations of `fstnum` and `secnum`.

Answer (score 4):

The arrows in this statement are incorrect.

```
cin << arithchoice;
```

should be replaced by this statement

```
cin>> arithchoice;
```

*Update*

The best way to remember which arrows to use with Cin and Cout is that with when inputing value you are pointing from outside to the computer. 
Similarly for *cout* you throw values from the computer to outside world.

So now if you want to pass values from real world to computer you which arrow will you use >>  *cin*
Similarly for giving results from computer to Real world(user) "<<"

```
              ----------------
              |               |
Real world    | <--- computer |
              |_______________|
```

Comment: Stupid mistake, thank you. And sorry for posting in off topic

Comment: It happens!...Everybody learns gradually.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I've noticed is that in the `(x==1)` if block, the arrows of the `cin` are the wrong way round.